# calling NSView from other class thats already initialized

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, initialization

How can I call an NSView that is already initialized with another window?

```
newContentView = [[CutoutView alloc]initWithFrame:window.frame]; //make a new CutoutView
    [window setContentView:newContentView]; //set it as the contentview of our window
    [newContentView release];
```

newContentView is an NSView subclass and it is set as the contentView of my window.  In the NSView subclass "CutoutView" I have it drawing a simple rect.

In another NSView subclass I want to be able to tell newContentView or just CutoutView that it needs to be redrawn by `[setNeedsDisplay:YES]` but the only way i can think of doing this is making another `[[CutoutView alloc] init];` and when I do that and call set needs display nothing works.  It says that it is doing it however it is not displaying probably due to the fact CutOutView is already initialized.  How can I access newContentView or just CutoutView from where it was already initialized so that way it will actually display.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you're thinking about classes the wrong way - that'll have to be remedied!

Comment: Where is this other NSView subclass?  Is it a subview of the content view or is it in another window? If the former, then you can get a reference to the content view with [self superview]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Methods from different classes twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155994/methods-from-different-classes-twice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So first and foremost, you need to get a reference to the particular instance of the `CutoutView` you created so you can tell that particular instance to redisplay itself.

You do this in a couple of ways:

- If you still have a reference to `window`, just call `[[window contentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES]`.
- Make the newContentView a property of a particular class so your other class can just access it... fundamentally you'll have to understand how classes really work in order to answer your question, because this isn't a technical problem, it's a conceptual one.

---

So the first problem is that you think your `CutoutView` represents an object, that, as you put it, "has already been initialized." This is the wrong way to think about it. `CutoutView` is a class, not an instance.

You've probably already heard the metaphor about a class and a blueprint, so I'll use something slightly different. `CutoutView` is a Toyota Prius - not the car, but the model, with the design blueprints and manufacturing process and everything. There's thousands of Priuses out on the road, the same way there can be thousands of instances of `CutoutView`.

Your question seemed to imply that you thought `CutoutView` is a car, a physical manifestation of a Prius sitting on a driveway; but it fundamentally isn't.

---

A *class* is a model, the design/brand of a Toyota Prius, or even the [Nimitz class aircraft carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimitz_class_aircraft_carrier), which describes a type of ship (of which there are 10). The *classes*, by themselves, don't mean much.

An *object*, or an *instance* of a *class*, is the actual thing your program works with. This is what *newContentView* in your code is. You just told it, metaphorically: (I hope this makes sense)

```
NimitzClassCarrier *USSGeorgeHWBush = [[NimitzClassCarrier constructBoat] prepareForLaunch];
```

[image]

^ The USS George H.W. Bush finished '`alloc`'ing in 2009 and was commissioned, `init`ed, and delivered to the Navy early that year.

[image]

^the *USS Nimitz* is another example of an *instance* of a Nimitz Class Carrier.

You've created an *instance* of the `CutoutView` class so you can actually work with it. You can create multiple *instances/objects* of the same class; there are 10 Nimitz class carriers, after all.

---

**Hence**,

You can't tell the USS George H.W. Bush to launch its planes by calling

```
NimitzClassCarrier *aCarrier = [[NimitzCarrierClass construct] prepareForLaunch];
[aCarrier launchPlanes];
```

Just think about it. All you're doing is spending millions building another carrier you know as "aCarrier" (a much less seaworthy name) and telling it to launch its planes.

**Instead**, what you want to do is to actually get a *reference* to the USS George H.W. Bush itself to tell it to launch its planes. So now lets go back to your `CutoutView`. You made an instance of `CutoutView` and sent it to your window for display. Then you basically sever the direct radio link between you and that instance by letting go of the *reference* (because I'm assuming you're having nothing to do with NewContentView ever again.

Fortunately, the window still has a direct radio communication link with the instance of `CutoutView` that you created. Hence, my first suggested option is to call `[[window contentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES]`, which tells your particular *instance* of `NSWindow` to get its `contentView` which happens to be the *instance* of `CutoutView` you want to display.

The number ways you can do what you want to do is, after all, endless. You can keep a direct radio communication link to your aircraft carrier and give that means of communication to the other instance of NSView you want to be able to send the aircraft carrier messages. You can cut off all direct communication with the `contentView` and let the window handle it all, telling the other instance of NSView to ask the window for a radio line.

<sup>*[Btw, how the heck do you communicate with aircraft carriers anyways? I don't think it's radio... In Objective-C it's having a pointer to the carrier/object's memory address, but boats are another world entirely.]*</sup>

Or, if as `rdelmar` asked in the comment way up there, the `instance` of NSView you want to be able to communicate with the contentView is actually a subview of the contentView... well, think of it this way. The 15th lifeboat wants to be able to tell the USS George HW Bush to launch its planes. How? `[[self parentBoat] launchPlanes]`. This translates into `[[self superview (a.k.a. parentNSView)] setDisplayNeeded:YES]`.

Also see @Dmorneault's answer about other ways you can establish radio communication with your esteemed aircraft carrier which you just sent into the Bermuda triangle.

The thing is, building a new `contentView/boat` doesn't do the trick, and that's what you're trying to do and that's the problem you're experiencing.

I don't think I explained very well, and apologies if this isn't new to you, but I thought your question indicated a misunderstanding in how classes work. I also know nothing about aircraft carriers, but that was the first thing I came across on Wikipedia.

Useful conceptual resources:

- [Oracle/Java conceptual docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)
- [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Im not totally sure how your code is setup but you should use properties to make references to objects.  Add the following to your .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CutoutView * newContentView;
```

Now in you .m file you can access the object with self.newContentView by adding

```
@synthesize newContentView = _newContentView;
newContentView = [[CutoutView alloc]initWithFrame:window.frame]; //make a new CutoutView
self.newContentView = newContentView;
[window setContentView:self.newContentView]; //set it as the contentview of our window
[newContentView release];
```

Comment: you said I can access the object with self.newContentView, but how would I format that in other classes?  `CutoutView *cutOut = [what do i put in here]`?

Comment: @GrantWilkinson `CutoutView *cutOut = whateverInstanceYouDefinedThePropertyFor.newContentView;`