# Change another class NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I know that this question is really old, but I'm having a lot of trouble accessing NSString's from another class;

Let's say that I have `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`, and from the `Second` I want to access a NSString called `string` - which is in `FirstViewController` -(okay, I know it's obvious). Here's the code of the `SecondViewController`:

```
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", viewController.string);
```

But the result is `(null)`, because it's getting the value from the `init` method.

Anyone have some tip/solution to access the `string` from any place that it's declared?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, @dasblinkenlight, I still get `(null)` as the string log.

Comment: @Alberto From your question it looks like reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159295/calling-nsview-from-other-class-thats-already-initialized/10159478#10159478 may help a bit (I may be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing what I think you are doing, you're creating a new version of `FirstViewController` within second view controller which, unless the `FirstViewController.string` is initialized to some value in the init block, is going to return a nul value.

What I think you want is to get the value of the string by accessing the item from the already-created `FirstViewController`. There are various ways to do this (depending on how you are pushing `SecondViewController` from the first and whether or not you are using Storyboards or not.

Comment: The `SecondViewController` is a subview from `FirstViewController`. Any idea?

Comment: Try casting `self.parentViewController` to `SecondViewController` and accessing its properties that way. `SecondViewController *parent = (SecondViewController*)self.parentViewController;    NSString* firstVCString = parent.stringProperty`;

Answer (score 0):

Global Variable is probably your answer. Unless you are in a tab bar controller, it is not possible to "PULL" the data from another class. It is possible to push your values from ViewController1 onto your ViewController2, but in order to pull it, I'd say global variable will save you lots of headache.